# What do the sentences in bold mean from Macgyver S01E01?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What do the sentences in bold mean from Macgyver S01E01?

I know the meaning of trade but I’m confused what dose it mean in this context, I thought it means the activity of selling and buying goods.

> MacGYVER: *It's funny, you know,*
> *the kind of stuff that
> pops into your head*
> *when you're trying to work.*
> *I remember there
> was this horse...*
> *A golden palomino.*
> ***Old Man McGinty had
> got him in a trade, I think**.*
> *I couldn't have been much
> more than nine or ten at the time,*
> *but I'd made up my mind I
> was going to ride that horse.*
> *'Course, knowing
> Old Man McGinty,*
> *that was going to
> take some doing.*
> *Well, first off, there
> was his dog, Hector.*
> *They didn't come any
> meaner or louder than Hector.*
> *One whiff of me
> heading for that corral,*
> *and Hector'd have the old
> man down on me like a shot.*
> ***So much for Hector**.*

Comment: Not only is this an unfathomable wall of text, but if we're to explain all the bold, that makes it seven questions in one; not suitable for SE.

Comment: He thinks that McGinty had acquired the palomino by an exchange with someone else, (probably for another horse).

Comment: Do you know the meaning of "trade" in this context?  If so, then  "get {the horse} in trade" should be easy to interpret.  So what is the specific difficulty with that line?  I'd like to write a good answer, but I don't know exactly what your misunderstanding is.

Comment: Kate Bunting, thank you for your help, I think it’s clear now.

James K, Yes, I know the meaning of trade but I’m confused what dose it mean in this context, I thought it means the activity of selling and buying goods, thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions with the same title or very similar titles: it's very confusing.

Comment: Ok Stuart, I will post different questions next time. 
There is phrase “ so much for Hector” I don’t get it yet, can you help me with it, and I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Trade generally means "buying and selling", but in this context it means "[an instance of bartering](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trade#Noun:%7E:text=An%20instance%20of%20bartering)"  That is, Old Man McGinty had not bought the horse with money, nor was it born in his stable, but he had exchanged something else for the horse.

The implication is that this is a better horse than McGinty could normally have been able to afford.

Comment: Thank you for your help,,